# Replace hyphen with a dash

Tags: regex

Replace every . (dot) with a - (hyphen) except when the dot is surrounded by digits. E.g.: `.a.b.1.2.` should become `-a-b-1.2-`

I tried the code

```
/(^\.|\.$|\b\.\b)(?!\d\.\B)/gm
```

Substitute

```
-
```

Result returned

Test 8/11: Read the task description again. Do not touch anything sandwiched between digits!

How do I modify the Regex?

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cmwx8J/4)

Comment: Which language you're using ?

Comment: It's the quiz exercise on Regex101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\D|^)\.|\.(?=\D|$)
```

and replace with `-`.

Explanation:

There are only 4 cases where you want to match a dot:

- there is a non digit before the dot
- the dot is the start of the string
- there is a non digit after the dot
- the dot is the end of the string

The regex just finds all four cases.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g6Ddwy/2)

As revo has suggested in the comments, this can be simplified to:

```
(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)
```

If lookbehind are not supported by your regex engine, you can replace them with groups:

```
(\D|^)\.|\.(\D|$)
```

and replace with `$1-$2`.

Comment: You could cut the alternation in favor of a negative lookaround e.g. `(?<=\D|^)` == `(?<!\d)`

Comment: This still doesen't handle `.a.b.1....2.` this case mate. you can consider updating accordingly

Comment: @CodeManiac It should work for that as well. There is no dots which are surrounded by numbers, So the expected output should be `-a-b-1----2-`.

Comment: @Sweeper i understood it as `digit followed by anything one or more character followed by digit` should not be touched. i am not sure what though what OP intended

Comment: @CodeManiac Since the OP has accepted my answer, I guess that means I handled the case correctly, right?

Comment: @Sweeper well logically this means so :) sorry for bothering. cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
(?<!\d|\.)\.+|\.+(?!\d|\.)
```

- `(?<!\d|\.)` - Negative lookbehind. to check preceding character is not digit
- `\.` - Matches `.`
- `(?!\d|\.)` - Negative look ahead to check following character is not digit

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bXYeSd/2/)

Comment: Your comment on question is important. It was better to wait for it. Currently you are not sure if it supports lookbehinds and it doesn't match `.` in `a.2` either.